# Безоговорочное лидерство по баллам кандидата в модераторы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дизайн

Проблемы со счётчиком баллов в модераторы 557 из 40. Нужно править алгоритм.

И не забыть перевести слово reputation.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-729505

Comment: Это интересно О_о Не связано ли с тем, что у него репутация меньше 1000 и показывается точным числом?.. А для тех, у кого больше, число делится на 1000 и прибавляется к счётчику. Угадайка. Но других возможных причин для такого бага я не вижу :)

Comment: @D-side так и есть, см. по дублоссылкам.

Comment: ---Цукерберг--- Чуров позвонит. ))